# Limit of Fraction

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(1 + x)^{x/(1 + x)}\cos^{4}x}{e^{x}}$$

Attempt: I've tried evaluating the limits of the terms individually using the property of limits. Also, $y=1/x$ subsituition hasn't helped me, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: For positive $x$, the top is $\ge 0$ and $\le 1+x$.
Now use Squeezing.

Comment: ah I see, the limit is 0, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, yes it is $0$, since $e^x$ grows much faster than $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that  $(1+x)^{\frac{x}{1+x}}=(1+x)(1+x)^{\frac{-1}{1+x}}$ and since $(1+x)^{\frac{-1}{1+x}}\to 1$ as $x\to \infty $ there is an $M>0$ such that

$0\leq \left | \frac{\left ( 1+x \right )^{\frac{x}{1+x}}cos^{4}x}{e^{x}} \right |<2(1+x)e^{-x}$ whenever $x>M$ so that as $x\to \infty $ the limit is $0$

Comment: The exponent is $\frac{x}{1+x}$. Your method will still work for this, since for $x\gt M$ we have $(1+x)^{x/(1+x)}\lt 2^x$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I apparently did a different problem. I will fix it